# omp_set_num_threads should I use it every time or can set it once?

Tags: c, openmp

I have a program that calls sequently about 100 functions - I want to use omp_set_num_threads for every function. Should I use it before every time I call ith function? Or can I use it once, lets say just after `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and it will be used for every function call?

It looks like this:

```
omp_set_num_threads(val);
if(call_me_i)
   call_ith_function;


omp_set_num_threads(val);
if(call_me_i+1)
   call_ith+1_function;
...
```

Comment: You only need to set the number of threads once - but you do need to be explicit about what loops (`for` etc) you want to be dispatched in parallel, using the appropriate `#pragma` preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you only need to set the number of threads once, unless you want to change it later. Once set, it is "remembered".

It sounds to me like you have individual functions that have some parallel code in them, and that you want to make sure that they indeed run in parallel.  When you have a large number of `if` statements, you usually want to consider a `switch`.

```
omp_set_num_threads(val); //<<< set just once
switch(whatFunction) {
  case fun1:
    callFunction1();
    break;
  case fun2:
    callFunction2();
    break;
  default:
    // etc
}

void callFunction1() {
  int ii;
  #pragma omp parallel
  // <<<< just this for loop will run in parallel >>>>>
  for(ii=0; ii<100; ii++) {
    // do stuff
  }
  printf("done\n"); printf("really done\n"); printf("totally done\n"); // << NOT in parallel
}

void callFunction2() {
  int jj;
  for(jj=0; jj<100; jj++) {
    // do stuff
  }  // <<<< this loop does NOT run in parallel since there is no #pragma in front of it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You should never use it!**

As soon as you use it you prevent your code from running optimally on someone else's machine, or on the machine you buy next year or the year after (by which time you'll have forgotten that you forced it).

If you use the Intel compiler it will default to using all the hardware threads that are available to the process (i.e. not masked out of the process' affinity mask) without you needing to do anything. Gcc may behave differently, but will certainly respect the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable which is a better place to choose the number of threads to use.

Building knowledge of your current machine into your code is simply a bad idea, because (as we now know), code lives much longer than hardware.

Comment: There are definitely situations where increasing the number of threads does not improve the speed of execution; this is particularly true when you have algorithms that use large amounts of shared memory, such as certain classes of tomographic reconstruction algorithms. In thoses cases, tuning the algorithm to a certain number of threads is necessary, and setting the number of threads is helpful. It is possible that different hardware will require a different optimization, but it is not true that "the compiler knows best". "Never say never".  Good point about longevity of software though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be a bit more clear, however I ll try to explain you how it works.

My cpu looks like this:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 28
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               1000.000
BogoMIPS:              3325.16
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             24K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              512K
```

Well, I have 4 logical cpu's. It means **omp_get_max_threads()** should return 4.

Here is my example code:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << omp_get_num_threads() << " " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
  omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());
  cout << omp_get_num_threads() << " " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
    cout << omp_get_num_threads() << " " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
    cout << "x" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
1 4
1 4
4 4
x
x
x
x
```

As you may see, **omp_set_num_threads()** have been called once at the beginning. However this call doesn't mean you run parallel since then.

To run instructions parallel, you need to use **#pragma omp parallel**. If it stands before section **{...}**, whole section will run parallel. If this is before normal line, it will affect only this line. Second approach appears after **#pragma omp single**. I call this, because I don't want every thread to print next line. I want just single one to print it.

Anyway, what you need is just to do following:

```
omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel
{
   if(call_me_i)
      call_ith_function;    

   if(call_me_i+1)
      call_ith+1_function;
}
```